# Automapper condition fallback

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, automapper

Context: RESTful ASP.NET Core Web API using AutoMapper 5.1.1.

I'm trying to achieve a generic way to expand referenced resources when the client requests it. E.g.:

`GET /api/Products/4711` returns

```
{
  "id":"4711",
  "productName":"flux capacitor",
  "category": {
    "id": "42",
    "obj": null,
  }
}
```

while `GET /api/Products/4711?expand=category` should return

```
{
  "id":"4711",
  "productName":"flux capacitor",
  "category": {
    "id": "42",
    "obj": {
      id:"42",
      name: "time travelling",
      isRestricted: true,
    },
  }
}
```

So far I managed to get to the point that it works by

#### 1. creating this class used as property in my resource:

```
public class ExpandableReference<TAggregateRoot,TResource>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TResource Obj { get; set; }
}
```

#### 2. This implementation of `ITypeConverter` (notice the use of my generic repository, that is successfully being injected here):

```
public class ReferenceExpander<TAggregateRoot, TResource> : ITypeConverter<int, ExpandableReference<TAggregateRoot, TResource>>
    where TAggregateRoot : AggregateRoot
{
    private readonly IRepository<TAggregateRoot> repository;

    public ReferenceExpander(IRepository<TAggregateRoot> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ExpandableReference<TAggregateRoot, TResource> Convert(
        int source, 
        ExpandableReference<TAggregateRoot, TResource> destination, 
        ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination = destination ?? new ExpandableReference<TAggregateRoot, TResource>();
        destination.Id = source;
        destination.Obj = ExpandReference(source, context);
        return destination;
    }

    private TResource ExpandReference(int source, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        TAggregateRoot aggregateRoot = repository.SingleOrDefault(source);
        TResource resource = context.Mapper.Map<TResource>(aggregateRoot);
        return resource;
    }
}
```

#### 3. providing this mapping configuration

```
CreateMap(typeof(int), typeof(ExpandableReference<,>)).ConvertUsing(typeof(ReferenceExpander<,>));
ForAllPropertyMaps(
    map => map.SourceType == typeof(int) && map.DestinationPropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ExpandableReference<,>),
    (map, expression) => expression.Condition((agg, res, _, __, ctx) => ctx.ShouldExpand(map.DestinationProperty.Name)));
```

where `ctx.ShoudExpand(string)` checks, whether the Items dictionary of ctx contains the destination property name. The controller is in charge of adding it when it comes to mapping from my domain object to a resource.

#### now the issue

`GET /api/Products/4711` returns

```
{
  "id":"4711",
  "productName":"flux capacitor",
  "category": null // what?!?!
}
```

with `category = null` because the condition says it should be omitted during mapping. What I need is a kind of fallback like this:

```
ForAllPropertyMaps(
    map => map.SourceType == typeof(int?) && map.DestinationPropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(OptionalExpandableReference<,>),
    (map, expression) => expression
        .Condition((agg, res, _, __, ctx) => ctx.ShouldExpand(map.DestinationProperty.Name))
        .Fallback(/*tell AutoMapper to just map the id, omit the obj*/));
```

- Moving the condition logic into the ITypeConverter implementation won't work, because there is no access to the target member name.
- Using two mappings won't work either, because AutoMapper is not designed to work this way. Would be a smart solution if we could inject an `IMapSelectionStrategy` with access to the MappingContext during configuration.
- Using an `IValueResolver` instead of an `ITypeConverter` cuts the nice way of configuration using open generics
- Ideas?

By the way: What could I expect and when does something other than null appears in the third and forth parameter of `expression.Condition((agg, res, ???, ???, ctx)`. I've never seen anything different than null.